How to add type hints for *args and **kwargs when one function forward arguments to another as is
Is it possible to add some type hints for A.a to specify that A.a must take x and y as arguments? Python 3.12+
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def a(*args, **kwargs) -> "B":
        return B(*args, **kwargs)

class B:
    def __init__(x: int, y: str):
        ...


This is a somewhat backwards example. A.a knows that it is calling B with its arguments, so it shouldn't simply accept arbitrary arguments and pretend it doesn't know what B wants.
